# Cannot Upload .GLB to Wordpress Media Location

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, 3d, glblendfunc

This is not a quick failure, I have spent a totally of 5 completely full days trying to figure this out. Initially I was limited by file size and then file type; in which I removed the Wordpress restrictions and am now "capable" of uploading my 177MB .glb file to Wordpress.

However when doing so, I receive the following error:

```
retriever.glb
Unexpected response from the server. The file may have been uploaded successfully. Check in the Media Library or reload the page.
```

I was on the phone with GoDaddy Specialists for 2.5 hours yesterday **ensuring** that this was not a Server issue or restriction on their side.. they confirmed that it **was not**. We pretty much ended the conversation that it is something I must figure out with me, myself, and I.

I went ahead and uploaded my .glb to the server through panel, everything worked fine. In fact I have a location for it here: https://www.tattiniboots.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/retriever.glb

However, this does not make the file discoverable to the 3D viewer plugins I have installed on the site through the media location.

I truly don't know where to go from here

I changed the name of the file to .png and attempted an upload and received the following error:

```
Post-processing of the image failed likely because the server is busy or does not have enough resources. Uploading a smaller image may help. Suggested maximum size is 2500 pixels.
```

I just tried to update a normal .mov file that is 150MB and received the following error; really making me think this is something to do with file size:

```
Unexpected response from the server. The file may have been uploaded successfully. Check in the Media Library or reload the page.
```

Yes, normal images are uploading just fine (2MB-ish)

I just attempted to deactivate all plugins with consideration that maybe "Smush" or another was imposing issues: I then received the issue that the file type is not supported (even with the allow all file types code in my wp-config)

Is this just the case that glb is not allowed at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be a server thing. probably a run time error
Whoever supported you just doesn't know it. GoGoDaddy. ;)

Nevertheless... you can Use a plugin that's called
**[media sync](https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-sync/)**. Check it out and best of luck

Comment: Right now I was able to call it using Babylon from the Cpanel. Just a side question to rest my mind. There would be no speed differention to have it in my actual Wordpress media location vs. my cpanel correct?

Comment: And as figured, GoDaddy had no idea what they were talking about. That was a 2.5hr phone call. GoMe & GoGoDaddy

Comment: Just tested a .glb file that was 3MB and it uploaded fine... wow

Comment: of course... they mean well but well.. ;) so you're sorted out?

Comment: Essentially. I am working on model compression now as this takes up to 3 minutes to load on desktop: https://www.tattiniboots.com/retriever-3d-view/. As for media sync, it will not work on that .glb file. It says imported successfully, but after viewing the media section it is not there, and a re-scan re-shows it. As asked before; there should be no difference in regards to speed if I just keep it on CPanel and don't have it in the media section correct?

Comment: yep, no difference at all

Comment: Thank you for the help!